# Fetching text data based on input given in jsp using ajax

Tags: html, sql, ajax, jsp

I want to get text field data based on input given by the user.

Here is my code.  This code will fetch data in dropdown(select), but I need to get data in text field.

```js
function getEventname() {
  var clid = $('#eventid').val();
  console.log("i am ok" + clid);

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "EduManage.jsp",
    data: {
      control: 'ajax',
      ch: '1',
      key: '1_0a1m_1',
      eventid: clid
    },
    success: function(data) {
      data = data.trim();
      addOptions(eventname, data.split(", "), data.split(", "));
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<td class="bg1">Event Id
  <edu:prnStar/>
  <a href="#" onClick="MM_openWindow('EduManage.jsp?control=search1&searchno=1_0s3&position=1','','width=790,height=420,left=0,top=70,scrollbars=1,location=no,status=no,resizable=yes')"><img src="../images/util/final.gif" name="search" width="20" height="20" alt="Search" border="0"></a>
</td>
<td class="bg1" width="25%">
  <edu:input name="eventid" type="text" id="eventid" size="10" maxlength="10" onblur="getEventname()" />
</td>
<td class="bg1" width="40%"> Event Name
  <edu:prnStar/>
</td>
<td class="bg1" width="25%"><input type="text" name="eventname" id="eventname">
</td>
```

In the key '`1_0a1m_1`' am having the query which is fetching the data

```
SELECT eventname FROM cam_eventdetail WHERE eventid=111
```

Comment: Please replace the JSP with HTML  - there is no select in your code. Any errors in the console?

Comment: I have to fetch only text field data.no need of select.

Comment: So what is the problem? I see `var clid = $('#eventid').val();` which is the value of a text field

Comment: clid is the eventid I have to get eventname based on clid(i.e( eventid))

Comment: What's stopping you? Please elaborate on your problem

Comment: I have to replace with some code instead of " addOptions(eventname, data.split(", "), data.split(", "));" this code to get eventnaame based on eventid.Please see my html